# File and logger was not created for slf4j

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logback, slf4j

In my application i am using slf4j for logger. I have used logback.xml for configuration. While am running main class i am getting correct response, meaning for my testing purpose i write one main class. But same configuration after build and deploy i am not getting any response. Logger file also not created and log was not captured.
Here i have mentioned my configuration xml file.

> logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <!-- Send debug messages to System.out -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- By default, encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Send debug messages to a file at "c:/jcg.log" -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>d:/Logs/truprovider.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>d:/Logs/truprovider.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
            <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
            <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.cts.emblem.batch" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <!-- By default, the level of the root level is set to DEBUG -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting default logger for my wildfly server. After modified the server configuration the problem will solved. Place the **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** file under **META-INF**.

> jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
      <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
      <module name="org.slf4j" />
      <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information that you've provided its hard to tell what happens, I suspect (just a wild guess) that logging infrastructure wasn't configured at all, because this file somehow hasn't propagated to the artifact (WAR, I assume)

When you run the application you can place a breakpoint on any log.*** message(like log.info) and check whether it has any assigned appenders in a list, again, as a hypothesis the list of appenders will be just empty.